# Storing file out of sandbox in iphone or Accessing filesystem by other applications

Tags: ios, filesystems, sandbox

The main objective of my application is to download pdf, html, doc etc file types from server and read it.

Now the requirement is , the files i have downloaded should be accessible by other reader applications that are already installed in the device. So how to allow my filesystem to be read by other applications?

Is there any possibility of storing filesystem in common location or outside sandbox, which will not be deleted when the user uninstall or delete the application from the device? The reason behind this question is that, the user should not loose his contents once downloaded, the user might read the downloaded files using other reader applicatiion that is already installed in his device.

Thanks in advance,

Shatthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The sandbox is there for a reason.

Comment: is it possible to allow other applications to read my pdf and doc files?

Comment: In a sense no, but if the app supports opening specific file types you can allow the user to open the file in this application via https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW16

Comment: In case of iPad apps it is indeed possible to allow other applications to read the pdf and files that are there in your app. In order to do that you would need to add a key UIFileShareEnabled in your info.plist file of your iPad app, and would need to add the document format you are planning to support. Rest of the details are available at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403